# In React Native, how can I avoid having a user click a submit button twice, when they are writing in a TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I have a very simple form for writing comments, with a `<TextInput>` and an `<IconButton>`:

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      mode={'outlined'}
      onChangeText={(val) => setCommentText(val)}
      value={commentText}
      label={'Write a comment...'}
    />
    <IconButton
      icon="send"
      onPress={addComment}
    />
  </View>
```

The problem is that users have to click the Send button twice. The first click just blurs the input and dismisses the keyboard, but the button doesn't register a click. Then when the TextInput is blurred they can actually click the Submit button.

How can I make it possible to click the Send button only once, when the `TextInput` has focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `onPress` to `onTouchStart` in the `<Button>` solved it. No need for tapping the button twice anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this behaviour is normal . if the keyboard is open and you want to interact with screen , first click will dismiss the keyboard and second one will work .
so as the best practice you can have a button within your keyboard which clicking on that will trigger the call request you want :

[image]

```
<TextInput
      mode={'outlined'}
      onChangeText={(val) => setCommentText(val)}
      value={commentText}
      returnKeyType="send"
      onSubmitEditing={() => {
        // call you api or whatever function here;
      }}
      label={'Write a comment...'}
      blurOnSubmit={false}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try This***

Add *keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" to ScrollView*

```
<SafeAreaView >
   <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">

      // ... place your code here
            
   </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```